# Can not see game objects after change their layer in reference prefab in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm creating a 2d game using Unity and get the following problem. When I change the layer of some game object in its reference prefab, I can not see that game object in the scene window.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity, cameras can view one or more layers simultaneously. If you have created a new layer, be sure that at least one of your cameras is set to render it. You may have placed your object on a layer which is not currently being rendered on any of your scene's cameras.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have set some layers as invisible. You can check visible layers in a popup list "Layers" at top right corner of Unity Editor window.